# Submit Values via POST to multiple PHP files

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a form :

```
<form action="moods.php" method="post" id="geog">
Longitude: <input size="15" id="lonbox" name="lon" type="text" />
Latitude: <input size="15" id="latbox" name="lat" type="text" />
<input type="submit"  />
</form>
```

I wish to submit the values of latitude and longitude to multiple .php files apart from moods.php at the same time using the single above form.

How can I do that?? please suggest some ways ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why have the form submit to multiple pages, when you can have one single script include() the other scripts?

```
require('script1.php');
require('script2.php');
require('script3.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could submit it to a file containing a cURL script that would handle multiple submissions

```
<form action="multi_submit.php" method="post" id="geog">
```

on multi_submit.php handle the form submission using [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to submit the values over multiple .php files, and the require option gave by dqhendricks does not solve it, why not to use several Ajax calls? One for each file.

You could have something like this:

```
<form onsubmit='sendSeveralPost()'>
... form fields
</form>
```

And the javascript function

```
function sendSeveralPost() {
    var f1 = document.getElementById('field1');
    var f2 = document.getElementById('field2');

    var x = getXmlHttp();

    var params = 'field1='+f1+'&field2='+f2;

    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    x.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    var files = new Array();
    files[0] = 'script1.php';
    files[1] = 'script2.php';
    files[2] = 'script3.php';

    for (i=0;i<files.lenght;i++) {
        var url = files[i];
        x.open("POST", url, true);

        x.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
             if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
                alert(x.responseText);
            }
        }
        x.send(params);
    }
}

function getXmlHttp() {
    var xmlHttp;
    try {    // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        try {     // Internet Explorer 6.0+
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            try {   // Internet Explorer 5.5
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}
```

Further explanations about the commands can be found at the article http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php, from where I took the inspiration for this example.

Hope this helps.

Namastê!

Comment: also I need to redirect to one of moods.php after passing on the field values to the multiple .php files .. how should I process further ??

Comment: you could redirect using javascript line: `window.location='http://www.mysite.com/moods.php'` or submit the form to this file using the javascript line: `document.getElementById('formId').submit();`

Comment: I have tried window.location earlier too .. where should I put that line ?? In sendSeveralPost() function at the end ??

Comment: @Ademire .. where should put the two lines of code mentioned by you ?? Please help ..

Comment: You should use one of this lines. window.location will redirect your browser, form.submit will submit the post ... I believe you should put it in the onreadystatechange function, after test if all posts have been send correctly. Be careful, this code is not complete, I just put the main idea, you should finish it with your logic need. Regards